Chrome/Chromium/Edge not open PDF file
Chrome PDF Viewer is not working, it just downloads the PDF file instead of opening it.
All members of the Chrome and Chromium family were unable to open PDFs, with only Firefox functioning normally.

I found that the registry was modified by the software like this. Delete the values. Problem solved.
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf]
"PerceivedType"="video"
"Content Type"="video/pdf"
@="Acrobat.Document.DC"

